# How to add visibility binding for MenuItem of ContextActions of a ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, visibility, menuitem

I am trying display context actions menu items while selecting any listview item, there I have added three menu items. But I need to bind the visibility for those Menu Items. Depending on selection the specific menuitem should be visible. Is there any way to add binding for the contextActions menuitems in a listview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a `ContextAction` is a [`MenuItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.menuitem?view=xamarin-forms) this is not possible. The `MenuItem` does not expose any (bindable) `IsVisible` property or alike.

A hacky workaround could be to add/remove context actions whenever you determine what needs to be shown or hidden. Or use the `IsEnabled` property that *is* available.